# Creating Bar Graph in Python with missing Dates

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn, missing-data

I would like to create a bar graph to show the number of sick people in a place each week using Python.
The end date of the week is to be input by the user.
The bar graph should show exactly 7 days before and including the end date even when the date is missing in the dataset.

The location is always the same and should be the title of the bar graph

Below is my dataset:

```
end_date = 2022-10-18

data = {'Date': [2022-10-14, 2022-10-14, 2022-10-14, 2022-10-15, 2022-10-16, 2022-10-16, 2022-10-17],
        'Location': ['Lion House', 'Lion House', 'Lion House', 'Lion House', 'Lion House', 'Lion House', 'Lion House']}
      
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My first objective is to transform df with all the dates from 2022-10-12 to 2022-10-18 with the relevant cases thus producing a dataframe as below.

```
data1 = {'Date': [2022-10-12, 2022-10-13, 2022-10-14, 2022-10-15, 2022-10-16, 2022-10-17, 2022-10-18],
        'Count': [0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0]}
      
df_transform = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

I know I can sum up the count using groupby and sum but I do not know how to insert the missing dates to create exactly one week and finally plot the graph.

[image: Below is a graph I plot using Excel]

Any help is much appreciated as I am new to Python.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can `reindex` after aggregation:

```
start_date = '2022-10-12'

idx = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D').astype(str)

(pd.crosstab(df['Date'], df['Location'])
   .reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
  # .plot.bar() # uncomment to see the plot
 )
```

Output:

```
Location    Lion House
2022-10-12           0
2022-10-13           0
2022-10-14           3
2022-10-15           1
2022-10-16           2
2022-10-17           1
2022-10-18           0
```

Graph:

[image: bar plot]

##### updated example

```
from pandas import Timestamp
d = {'Date_of_Consult': [Timestamp('2022-10-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-10-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-10-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-10-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-10-13 00:00:00')], 
     'Dorm_Address': ['Shaw Lodge Dormitory', 'Shaw Lodge Dormitory', 'Shaw Lodge Dormitory', 'Shaw Lodge Dormitory', 'Shaw Lodge Dormitory']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

start_date = '2022-10-12'
end_date = '2022-10-18'
idx = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D') #.astype(str)

(pd.crosstab(df['Date_of_Consult'], df['Dorm_Address'])
   .reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
  # .plot.bar() # uncomment to see the plot
 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Apologies but my graph shows no output. I also needed the title to be lion house, no legend. And is it possible to input x-axis as date and y-axis as count?

Comment: Then slice just before plotting: `['Lion House'].plot.bar()`

Comment: If the plot is not shown you might not be in interactive mode. Try `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in the preamble and `plt.show()` after your plot.

Comment: Sorry, I am running it in a for loop to output 20 graphs at a go. I do not know how to slice it.

Comment: Imported and added plt.show() and the graph still does not come out.

Comment: Well, I don't know your setup, make sure to first follow the matplotlib documentation or a tutorial and ensure you can display a plot.

Comment: Can I check if fill_value should be equals to 0 cos everything is 0 when I print out the reindex

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input (yours is invalid): `df.head().to_dict('list')`

Comment: I think the main issue is where you produce the idx, is in string format whereas the date in the df is datetime. When I remove .astype(str), the graph is plotted. Thank you for your help. Can I ask how to add title, add axis-title and remove legend?

Comment: Both should work fine (at least in my pandas version: 1.5.0), I provided a complete code that runs fine for me